# How to analyze headers in PHP

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I'm using a `file_get_contents` to interact with an API for simple `GET` requests... however sometimes it throws headers signifying there's been an error.  How can I get these headers and determine if there's a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use curl instead of file_get_contents.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

I imagine if your communicating with a REST Api then your actaully wanting the Http Status code returned. In which case you could do something like this:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/api/users/1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 501) {
    echo 'Ops it not implemented';
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: +1. Also file_get_contents doesn't always work with web url, depending on the server config.

Answer (score 5):

Php will set $http_response_header after `file_get_contents` which contains the response headers as an array of header lines/strings. Its not necessary to use curl if all you want is the headers responses (and probably shouldn't, some LAMP stacks still don't have cURL).

**Doc on $http_response_header:** http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

**Example:**

```
file_get_contents('http://stacksocks.com');

foreach ($http_response_header as $header)
{
    echo $header . "<br>\n";
}
```

**Tips taken from post in comments:**

> 1) The value changes with each request
>   made.
>
> 2) When used in methods/functions, the
>   current value must be passed to the
>   method/function.  Using
>   $http_response_header directly in the
>   method/function without being assigned
>   a value by a function/method parameter
>   will result in the error message: 
>   Notice: Undefined variable:
>   http_response_header
>
> 3) The array length and value
>   locations in the array may change
>   depending on the server being queried
>   and the response received.  I'm not
>   sure if there are any 'absolute' value
>   positions in the array.
>
> 4) $http_response_header ONLY gets
>   populated using file_get_contents()
>   when using a URL and NOT a local file.
>   This is stated in the description when
>   it mentions the HTTP_wrapper.

Comment: This really helped me make sense of $http_response_header - http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/head-first-with-php-streams/

Answer (score 0):

```
file_get_contents('http://example.com');
var_dump($http_response_header);
```